# Create offset for axis - X and Y should meet at 0, not Y-axis min value

Tags: c3.js

I am using c3.js to show temperature values, as a range I expect values from -30 to +50 degrees.

This works fine so far, but I am unhappy with the graphical representation.

I would like to have my X axis meet the Y axis at 0 and not at -30. Is this possible with c3.js? I already had a look at the manual and the examples, but I didn't find anything regarding offsetting the axis in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide default axis (1) and add custom line at zero (2).

[See in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/8b4w4tfq/1/) (jsfiddle)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 20, -10, 40, 15, -25]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            show: false // (1)
        },
        y: {
            max: 50,
            min: -30,
            // center: 0,
        }
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{ value: 0, text: 'zero' }] // (2)
        },
    },
});
```

Related docs:

1. http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-show
2. http://c3js.org/reference.html#grid-y-lines

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into this in the evening.